# `UnityEngine.WorldParticleCollider' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Anyone knows why im getting inaccessible due to its protection level?
here's the code below

```cs
public static Component AddComponent(GameObject tarObject, Component srcCom) {
    if (srcCom.ToString().Contains("EllipsoidParticleEmitter")) 
        return tarObject.AddComponent<EllipsoidParticleEmitter>();

    if (srcCom.ToString().Contains("MeshParticleEmitter")) 
        return tarObject.AddComponent<MeshParticleEmitter>();

    if (srcCom.ToString().Contains("WorldParticleCollider")) 
        return tarObject.AddComponent<WorldParticleCollider>();

    Component com = tarObject.AddComponent(srcCom.GetType());

    return com;
}
```

Comment: It isn't public. Maybe because it is legacy? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WorldParticleCollider.html

Comment: You probably rather want to use the [CollisionModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html) from the new [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html)